# In elasticsearch can 1 Parent Type have multipe child Type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I know that there is a way in which 1 parent Type can have 1 Child Type in elastic search using :

```
PUT /company
{
"mappings": {
"branch": {},
"employee": {
  "_parent": {
    "type": "branch" 
     }
   }
  }
}
```

How can we create 2 Child Type relation with 1 Parent type ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there is no limitation for that idea of child/parent is about routing, it means that parent and child must be saved within one shard.

But there is limitation that 1 child can have only 1 parent.

So technically you can have parent company with multiple children such as contractors, employee.

```
POST /city/company/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "contractors",
            "score_mode": "max",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "name": "Alice Smith"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "employee",
            "score_mode": "max",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "name": "Alice Smith"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

So this query will search in index **city** for companies which have document of type employee or contractor who match name **Alice Smith**

More about relations [read here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html)

Comment: I am a beginner to elastic search. Can you explain How exactly can we form query DSL ?